# Why does Selenium run slower if the mouse is on the primary monitor with the browser session

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium

So this is weird, and it's not exactly an issue we can't get around, but we are able to slow down Selenium just based off of the location of the mouse.  Let's say you have 3 monitors.  If you run the test on your primary monitor and have your mouse on that same monitor, the tests will run significantly slower.  To avoid this, you can literally just position the mouse on a different monitor.  We don't even use any commands that use the cursor to determine where to look.

This is more of a curiosity thing.  Does anyone know why this is the case?  Seems like the cursor really shouldn't affect anything...

I'm using:

```
Selenium 2.44
Windows 7
IE 9/10/11
Python 2.7
```

Comment: What if you leave the mouse on the same monitor, but then unplug it? It could be related to how Windows handles the mouse, but that's not much to go on.

Comment: didn't change anything

Comment: What if you switch to Chrome or Firefox? Still reproducible?

Comment: The software I'm testing is supposed to be IE specific.  With that being said, it still for most part works in Chrome - I tried running the test there and it seemed to work fine. So, it's probably IE... not like that's ever been a problem or anything...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try next [DesiredCapabilities](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#WebDriver): enablePersistentHover = false; requireWindowFocus = false;

Also, you can update Selenium and [IEDriver](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.46/) to 2.46

Comment: hmm, didn't seem to affect it.  I updated Selenium and the driver, though - seems like it would be smart to do